# Reference for autocorrelation formula for vectors

Tags: references, autocorrelation, vector

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844295/computing-autocorrelation-of-vectors-with-numpy) on Stack Overflow says that the autocorrelation, or self correlation, of vectors is defined as

$$C(t, \{v\}_n) = \frac {1}{n-t}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1-t}\vec v_i\cdot\vec v_{i+t}$$

What is the source of this formula? Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation